# Executing DevCon CMD command from python

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, devcon

I want to restart driver with DevCon from python script. It works from command line with this command:

```
devcon restart \"sd0007322081041363_kcanv\"
```

I tried this:

```
os.system("devcon restart \"sd0007322081041363_kcanv\"")
```

with result:

```
'devcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I read that os.system is obsolete and i need to use subprocess.check_output so i try this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['devcon', 'restart', '"sd0007322081041363_kcanv"'])
```

with result:

```
WindowsError:[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and this:

```
subprocess.check_output('devcon restart "sd0007322081041363_kcanv"', shell=True)
```

with result:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'devcon restart "sd0007322081041363_kcanv"' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

and this:

```
subprocess.Popen("devcon restart \"sd0007322081041363_kcanv\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

result:

```
'devcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

and this:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('devcon disable "sd0007322081041363_kcanv" /f',shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

with result:

```
RuntimeError: command 'devcon disable "sd0007322081041363_kcanv" /f' return with errpr (cpde 1): 'devcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

devcon.exe is under Windows/System32 and it is set in system path.

I know that this can be duplicate question but I have tried many solution on stackoverflow but i van't resolve this issue.

Comment: Try specifying the full path and .exe extension of devcon.

Comment: @lit I have tried it with 
    `subprocess.Popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\devcon.exe restart \"sd0007322081041363_kcanv\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()`   but result is almost the same. Result:   `'C:\Windows\System32\devcon.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a solution. I tried many things but this is what works for me:

1. copy devcon.exe from C:\Windows\System32 and put it to C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
2. my code:

   ```
   try:
       subprocess.check_output('C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\devcon.exe restart "sd0007322081041363_kcanv" /f',shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
       raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
   ```